# Normed-Space; bound needed for $||x|| + ||y|| - ||x+y||$

Tags: geometry, normed-spaces

Given x and y, is there any way we can express $||x|| + ||y|| - ||x+y||$ in terms of $||y-x||$? Even a bound where $||x|| + ||y|| - ||x+y|| \leq f(||y-x||)$ for some $f(\cdot)$ would be desirable.

Geometrically, ||x|| and ||y|| could be two sides of a parallelogram and then $||x+y||$ and $||y-x||$ would be its diagonals.

Comment: I will put back the way the quesiton was originally, and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$||x||+||y||-||x+y|| \\
= ||x||-\frac{||x+y||}{2}+||y||-\frac{||x+y||}{2} \\ 
\le ||x -\frac{x+y}{2}|| + ||y -\frac{x+y}{2}|| \\
\le \frac{||x-y||}{2} +  \frac{||y-x||}{2}  \\
\le ||y-x||$$

Comment: Very nice! I just want to comment that the last two $\leq$ could be changed to $=$. It is not wrong what you wrote, but having only one $\leq$ will point out more clearly (in my opinion) what is happening.

Comment: I left the $\le$ not to confuse the reader if he only reads first and last line