# Normed-Space; lower bound needed for ||x||+||y||−||x+y||

Tags: geometry, normed-spaces

Looking for an $f(\cdot)$ such that $||x|| + ||y|| - ||x+y|| \geq f(||y-x||)$

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534942/normed-space-bound-needed-for-x-y-xy) we had a question for the lower-bound version, where the result is that $||x|| + ||y|| - ||x+y|| \leq ||y-x||$

Comment: There isn't one other than $f(d) \equiv 0$. (if you meant $f(||y-x||)$). Consider $y=2x$

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo on your right hand side? I assure you mean $f(||y||-||x||)$. If so, every $f(\cdot)$ that is monotonically decreasing should do the trick. What is left to check are the limits on $x$ and $y$

Comment: And $f(0)=0$, so again it's no better than $f(d) \equiv 0$.